# Rails - has_many count on validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm doin' some validation on a parent model that save nested attributes for a child model. My parent has_many childs and my validation checks if the count of those childs is greater than 0. It works fine for editing, since the childs are already created and saved on db, but for new records it fails, since the count always returns 0. How can I fix that?

my parent model code looks like:

```
class ArrendamentoContrato < ApplicationRecord



  has_many :arrendamento_contrato_unidades, dependent: :destroy

  validate :check_total_percentual_credito

  def check_total_percentual_credito
    if arrendamento_contrato_unidades.count > 0 && arrendamento_contrato_unidades.sum(&:percentual_credito).to_f != 100.0
      self.errors.add :percentual_credito, I18n.t("errors.messages.percentual_credito")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This goes back to my answer to your last question, your parent recorded is not saved yet but you want to validate that the children records associated with the parent model exist before the parent model exist (in the context of the database) its kinda a chicken before the egg issue. Thats why I made that suggestion about moving the logic to the controller, though I do see some issues with that. I look forward to the answers on this one.

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII I appreciate your answer and I got what you mean... but I really don't like to put that kind of code on controller... there's gotta be some way to do it in model, I believe

Comment: Yea I understand that, I look forward to hearing alternate approaches.

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII changing the method count for size solved the problem... for now, it does the trick!

Comment: never mind  I get it.

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII yeah, like in the code above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your validation for update only

```
validate :check_total_percentual_credito, on: :update
```

Comment: but I want it validates on create too. The problem is, even if I have my child models, on create check it doesn't validate, 'cause the count for those is always as 0, even if I have some

Comment: How can you have children associated with a parent if the parent doesn't even exist in the database yet?

Comment: So, I'm creating the parent with the children (nested attributes - cocoon gem), but, in the moment I'm validating that parent, I only wanna do that validation if there's at least one of these childrens, got it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem: changing .count for .size did the trick. Hope it helps someone!